# Exporting to PDF from Google Sheets removes emoji

Tags: google-sheets, pdf, printing, emoji, unicode

I have designed a schedule in Google Sheets that uses emoji to indicate the character of each days activities. They display perfectly in Google Sheets. I want to physically print the sheet but when I try to export to PDF they disappear leaving behind the dreaded crossed boxes. I have also tried to export to HTML and then print the resulting page. This does preserve the emoji but badly breaks the layout on print.

My question is this-- can it be done? Can I print emoji from google sheets or will I have to redo my work in a different program.

Comment: Hey, seems like an encoding issue, not sure what can be done. 
Try maybe some picture instead of emojis ? [here's an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WzZYaqG1JTFq9od6XUNKbETGz_XHUR_WK5qYFeRwMa0/edit?usp=sharing). You can check for corresponding image at https://emojipedia.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using image instead of emojis?

[here's a sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WzZYaqG1JTFq9od6XUNKbETGz_XHUR_WK5qYFeRwMa0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=IMAGE("https://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/face-with-tears-of-joy.png")
```

Links of images come from [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/grinning-face/).

Answer (score 4):

I exported the document to excel and it shows the emojis and then they print from there.

Comment: This doesn't work in my old version of Excel 2007, but perhaps it does in more recent versions.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have to choose exact font, emoji containing cells that are formatted with "Inconsolata" or "Sawarabi Mincho" are perfectly exported to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

I've reported this as an issue here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241147770

Please vote the issue if you want Google to solve it.

---

Note: when I use fonr `Noto Emoji` emojis are printed, but they are not colored.

[image]

To use this font select 'More Fonts' option.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

As I explained in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73224033/19529694)

- Export your Sheet as Web page (.Html)

[image]

- Open with a browser and save as a PDF
- Open the PDF with a PDF editor or Illustrator and delet columns and rows grids

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was instead of choosing to Download PDF via **"File > Download > PDF"**, try the following: **"File > Print > Next > Destination > Save As PDF"** (click the dropdown showing your printer). This will export with the emojis.